# Any Reason Why Repodiff Doesn't Work as Intended When Specifying Arch?

Tags: centos, repository, diff, centos6, yum

So I've been in the process of using repodiff to determine the differences between two local repositories and when I use the normal `repodiff -o /old/repo -n /new/repo` I obviously get the warning saying "`** No 'src' pkgs in any repo. maybe see docs. on --archlist?`". However when I add `-a x86_64` or `--archlist=x86_64`, whether in the beginning or the end, I still get the same error. I even deleted an x86_64 rpm from the old repo just to make sure it wasn't a "No differences found" kind of error. In case it matters, I've also messed with adding `--compare-arch` and using `--old=` and `--new=` instead of the shorthand just to see if those made any difference, but alas nothing.

I just ran `repodiff -a x86_64 -o /old/repo -n /new/repo` on a clean CentOS 6 VM and the command works as I originally intended. I can run it side by side and the VM works but my normal system does not. The only difference I see in the output other than the obvious, is `Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile` for each repo on the real machine and a `refresh-packagekit` plugin on the VM.

Is there something that I'm missing here or is this a bug with my host? If it is indeed a bug, what can I do to fix it? Reinstall yum-utils? Or is it likely more to do with my system as a whole?

Comment: I have gone through and deleted everything out of the `/var/cache/yum/` directory and `/var/tmp/yum-*` with no luck. The only other behavior I have seen that may be relevant is that there is an `old1` and `new1` folder inside the `/var/tmp/yum-*` directory that keep showing up in the current working directory after running the repodiff command and failing.

Comment: For now, I am chalking it up to a bug on the system somewhere. Since running the same command, with the same permissions, on the same directories, on a separate machine produces different results I don't think it's an issue with my syntax or other mistakes. I have resorted to just using the `diff` tool for the time being.